# How to dispatch multiple actions in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have this effect

```
loadFirms$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(SidebarAction.loadFirmList),
        switchMap((action) =>

          this.sidebarService.getFirms(action.userId).pipe(
           map(firmList => {
               let firms: Firm[] = [];
               Object.keys(firmList).map(value => {
                 let keyArray = value.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ');

                 firms.push({
                   id: parseInt(keyArray[0]),
                   firmName: keyArray[1],
                   roles: firmList[value]
                 });

          });

          return SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess({firms});
        }),
      )
    )
    );
});
```

On loadFirmList action (that has a userId payload used as parameter) I want to do a "getFirms" GET request, edit the related response (i edited an object into an array of objects) and pass this new array like payload to loadFirmSuccess. This works fine but I need also to use the properties into the "firms" array for doing another http get calls. I thought the best way was to dispatch another action like this:

```
loadFirms$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(SidebarAction.loadFirmList),
        switchMap((action) =>

          this.sidebarService.getFirms(action.userId).pipe(
           map(firmList => {
               let firms: Firm[] = [];
               Object.keys(firmList).map(value => {
                 let keyArray = value.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ');

                 firms.push({
                   id: parseInt(keyArray[0]),
                   firmName: keyArray[1],
                   roles: firmList[value]
                 });

          });

          return [SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess({firms}),SidebarAction.loadDocuments({firms}) ];
        }),
      )
    )
    );
});
```

on the dispatch of loadDocuments I would call the other http get service: "loadDocuments".
What's the best approach for doing it?

Comment: You dont have a loadFirmFailure action here, but imagine you do. Then you would call the loadDocuments Action also on failure. The best way would be to dispatch loadDocuments from the loadFirmSuccess effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to dispatch multiple actions from one effect:

```
switchMap((action) =>
  this.sidebarService.getFirms(action.userId).pipe(
    map(firmList => {
      let firms: Firm[] = [];
      Object.keys(firmList).map(value => {
        let keyArray = value.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ');

        firms.push({
          id: parseInt(keyArray[0]),
          firmName: keyArray[1],
          roles: firmList[value]
        });
      });
      return firms;
    })
  )
),

// time to dispatch multiple actions
switchMap((firms) => [
  new SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess({firms}),
  new SidebarAction.loadDocuments({firms})
])
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But what's the "new"? Is this for creating object? Actions are not functions?

Comment: My action is like this: `export const loadFirmSuccess = createAction(
'[Sidebar] Load Firm List success',
  props<{ firms: Firm[] }>()
);`

Comment: Usually an `Action` is an interface, which will be implemented by classes. If you would do it "vanilla" style, it would look something like `export class AddAction implements Action {...}`. The function `createAction` should therefore return an object, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
return [SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess({firms}),SidebarAction.loadDocuments({firms}) ];
```

Inside of your `getFirms` map handler:

```
loadFirms$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(SidebarAction.loadFirmList),
        switchMap((action) =>

          this.sidebarService.getFirms(action.userId).pipe(
           map(firmList => {
               let firms: Firm[] = [];
               Object.keys(firmList).map(value => {
                 let keyArray = value.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(', ');

                 firms.push({
                   id: parseInt(keyArray[0]),
                   firmName: keyArray[1],
                   roles: firmList[value]
                 });
              return [SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess({firmList}),SidebarAction.loadDocuments({firmList}) ];
          });


        }),
      )
    )
    );
});
```

Your inner observable can map to an array of actions, or array of observables which map to actions.  In this case, you're mapping to an array of actions.